# Change default branch path name in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

We have a trunk branch in TFS called **Main**.  From that we create bug/feature branches that should go into their own folder.  We had created a folder called **Development** for this purpose, so when we branched we would specify...

```
$/TFS/Development/{branchname}
```

However, we noticed TFS defaulted the path to...

```
$/TFS/Main-branch
```

So we thought, we'll just rename **Development** to **Main-branch** and life will be good.  And we did.

Now the problem is TFS defaults the path to...

```
$/TFS/Main-branch1
```

I realize this is severely in the "first world problem" category, but is there a way to change the default path TFS uses?   I have found other SO posts that indicate this cannot be done, but I was hoping there was something we could do for TFS2013.

Comment: There is a tool from the ALM Rangers that might help you out. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ce9651af-671c-4148-987f-a91820646031 Other than that, the only thing you could do is write your own Branch command as a Visual Studio Extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change this behavior without code.

It is the same behavior as creating a new folder in windows explorer and it being "NewFolder"...

It's kinda deliberate so you give it a proper name